# Why does diff.time Return NA values, console shows no error.?

Tags: r, na, difftime

I am here trying to calculate the time difference between two date formats, first, I have been faced with various errors such as

- `as.POSIXlt.character` : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
- Values unable to parse
- `NA` values added by coercion

however, with trials, I have reached this next line of code that runs with no errors or warnings but the return values are all `NA`

```r
Rides_cleaned <-
  Rides %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  mutate(rideduration=difftime(as.numeric(as.POSIXct(ended_at,format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p")),
                               as.numeric(as.POSIXct(started_at,format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p")), units = "mins"))
```

[image]

Comment: This is a datetime format problem. Try `as.POSIXct("6/4/21 7:45",format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")`

Comment: This gives me the following error : 
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `rideduration = difftime(...)`.
Caused by error in `as.POSIXct.numeric()`:
! 'origin' must be supplied
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to use the correct date format, `as.numeric` isn't needed either:

```
Rides <- data.frame(started_at="6/4/21 7:45",ended_at="6/4/21 7:46")

Rides %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  mutate(rideduration=difftime(as.POSIXct(ended_at,format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M"), 
                               as.POSIXct(started_at,format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M"), 
                               units = "mins"))

#   started_at    ended_at rideduration
#1 6/4/21 7:45 6/4/21 7:46       1 mins
```

Comment: This Works !
thanks so much, so my bug was using the extra as.numeric ?

Comment: Yes, to convert a date to numeric you need to specify an origin (usually `1970-01-01`) so that number of seconds since this origin can be calculated.